# Tkinter login form

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to do a user and password input box I want to close the window after login and create a new window but its keep show missing 1 required positional arguement

```
import tkinter as tk
def enter(window):
    if ipt.get()=='admin' and ipt1.get() == 'admin':
        window.destroy()
        window=tk.Tk()
        window.geometry('1000x600+260+100')
        window.resizable(0, 0)
window=tk.Tk()
window.geometry('200x80')
window.resizable(0,0)
lbl = tk.Label(text='Name:')
lbl.grid(row=0,column=0)
lbl1=tk.Label(text='Password:')
lbl1.grid(row=1,column=0)
ipt=tk.Entry()
ipt.grid(row=0,column=1)
ipt1=tk.Entry(show='*')
ipt1.grid(row=1,column=1)
btn=tk.Button(text='Login',command=enter)
btn.grid(row=2,column=1)



window.mainloop()
```

Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: enter() missing 1 required positional argument: 'window'
```

Comment: Try `btn=tk.Button(text='Login',command=lamdba:enter(window))` ?

Comment: you don't need a window parameter in the enter function. You can just set `window` as `global`. something like `def enter(): global window`.

Answer (score 0):

You defined the function with

```
def enter(window):
```

But you didn't pass the window variable to the function. So when you define the button use this:

```
btn=tk.Button(text='Login',command=lambda: enter(window))
```

You can read more about lambda here https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp

Comment: Not passing the `window` argument to the function means the function is now using a global variable — which has long been considered a poor programming practice and shouldn't be recommend IMO.